# Mixing Primefaces 3.5 and Richfaces 4.3, will the bundled jQuery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I'm developing a JSF project in which I must integrate both component libraries. In last versions the main problem was the jquery.js version and extras implementation in jQuery. I've looked the new version of PrimeFaces and RichFaces libraries and I noticed that both have the same jquery.js version. Can I work with both without conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Richfaces 4.3.2 and Primefaces 3.5 together as they both include the same jQuery version 1.8.3, but it terribly **failed**.

The inspection if head-script order did not help.

This observation may help you: the problems even persisted, as I completely removed any primefaces components; removing the primefaces.jar (or going back to primefaces 3.3.1) **DID** solve the problems.